# Epplus Drawings with Negative Position Values

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm opening an excel file using EPPlus and the problem is that when I open the file, several ExcelDrawing in WorkSheet.Drawings have their "To" proprety with its values negative.

```
To.Column = -2147483648 
To.ColumnOff = -2147483648 
To.Row = -2147483648 
To.RowOff = -2147483648
```

Anyone knows how can I fix this issue?

Code :

```
using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Files\test.xlsm")))
{
   foreach (ExcelWorksheet ws in pack.Workbook.Worksheets)
   {
       foreach (ExcelDrawing drw in ws.Drawings)
       {
           if (drw.To.Column > ExcelPackage.MaxColumns || drw.To.Column < 1)
           {

               Console.WriteLine(ws.Name + "|" + drw.Name);
           }
      }
   }
   pack.Save();
}
```

Comment: That is the value of `Int32.MinValue`. It likely indicates that the proerties have no meaningful value but they are non-nullable. What does this mean in terms of the drawing? Maybe they are not bound to a specific row/column.

Comment: The problem is that Epplus throws an exception when saving because of this.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code you are using to save and the exception details? You didn't mention anything about an exception.

Comment: It's invalid operation exception, "Column number out of bounds"

Comment: This was the code I made to find out why there was problem and thats what I found out. Im not chaging anything but still gets this error. I already tried to set drw.To.Column = ExcelPackage.MaxColumns -1 but its not setting the value.